# .htaccess Rewrite Rule Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am having error in the files.
This is my `.htaccess` file.
Redirecting error is mainly that it is showing a 404 error when I click login button then it redirects me to `mydomain.com/login` which shows me a 404 error as in the file ...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 /warning/notfound
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes   
IndexIgnore *
```

Comment: I tried to edit your question but I couldn't... too broad.

Comment: I had edited the code and shorten it to much extent now all other things are related therefore can't be removed ..

Comment: So what is your problem? What is the URL your type in your browser that is  a problem?

Comment: I have uploaded my content on vgamerzz.cf visit there and click on login theres the problem ..

Comment: If I try "`https://vgamerzz.cf/`" I get Host Error, if I try `https://vgamerzz.cf/login` then I get `Error 526 Invalid SSL certificate`

Comment: Yeah please try again without https

Comment: It redirects me to `https://` and I get the same error

Comment: Okay I have removed https redirection now you can continue in a minute ...

Comment: I get `The requested URL /home/vol4_3/vapphost.ga/www/vgamerzz.cf/htdocs/login.php was not found on this server.` So far it's good, this only means you didn't provide "`login.php`". If it's not the right file, what *exactly* should be the right file? Give us the full name/full path

Comment: I tried adding .php extension in the url which showed me the page now , there is an error in htaccess file rewrite rule

Comment: I wrote an answer, I see you're trying a lot of things to solve your problem, if I gave you enough information, say it **`8^)`** Have a nice evening!

Comment: Thanx for the help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Now I have the answer actually there should be a slash here ..

```
RewriteRule ^login$ /login.php
```

This just solved my problem ...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear (to the least!) but here's the "translation" of your `.htaccess` file:

- `ErrorDocument 404 /warning/notfound` if there's a `404` then redirect to `/warning/notfound`
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` if the requested URL is *not* a directory then try to apply the next rule
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` Whatever is in the URL, if it ends with a `/` then remove it *and stop URL rewriting rules* (**`L`** = stop)
- `RewriteRule ^login$ login.php` if the URL is `login` then redirect to `login.php`

Maybe the **`L`** is the source of your problem?
I hope I gave you enough clues to solve your problem!